# Is Linux-based hardware-specific password generation and/or file encryption/decryption possible?

Tags: linux, password-encryption

*This might be a question for Superuser but I would prefer a programmatic way to handle this if a tool doesn't already exist.*

Basically I'm trying to find a method of generating a consistent, hardware/software installation specific password/key that can be used for file based encryption. By file based encryption, I mean decrypt a file. I want that file to only decrypt with a password that isn't stored anywhere, and can be consistently re-created from looking at the machine hardware/software.

Problem with digging into this is the starting point is "Linux file encryption" which is well covered by whole disk encryption. e.g. TruCrypt, etc... Disk encryption is overkill.

Any pointers, programmatic or otherwise are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a password that isn't stored anywhere, and can be consistently re-created from looking at the machine hardware/software.

To say that your hardware and/or software will never change is usually an invalid assumption.  How do you know that your next system patch won't change whatever "key" you are using to generate your password?

You might be better off with a system like [Stanford PwdHash](https://www.pwdhash.com/) (there are also command-line tools available) that will generate a password based on a different but known password and a salt (typically, the domain name, but you can put whatever you want in that field).